# Can I convert a string representation of a JSON object within a JSON into JSON value using PowerShell?

Tags: json, powershell

I have created a PowerShell script that gets the contents of a file as a string (via `Get-Content -Path $_.FullName`), which it then stores in my JSON array as a string.  But I want Contents to be a JSON object, not a String representation of a JSON object.  How do I do that?

What I have so far:

```
[
  {
    "LastWriteTime": "2023-03-07T15:22:07.8269947-05:00",
    "FullName": "\\\\server\\d$\\Program\\logs\\alerts\\2480702_2023-03-07-202100Z_1678220527823.json",
    "Contents": "{\"a\":12345,\"b\":\"This is a test\\nof wills.\\n\",\"c\":[\"ABC006\",\"ABC502\",\"ABC503\"]}"
  },
  {
    "LastWriteTime": "2023-03-08T15:18:58.4251682-05:00",
    "FullName": "\\\\server\\d$\\Program\\logs\\alerts\\2480702_2023-03-08-201800Z_1678306738418.json",
    "Contents": "{\"a\":23456,\"b\":\"To\\nstack overflow\\n\",\"c\":[\"ABC006\",\"ABC502\",\"ABC503\"]}"
  },
  {
    "LastWriteTime": "2023-03-09T15:06:18.6890386-05:00",
    "FullName": "\\\\server\\d$\\Program\\logs\\alerts\\2480702_2023-03-09-200600Z_1678392378684.json",
    "Contents": "{\"a\":34567,\"b\":\"or not to\\nstack overflow\\nthat is the question.\\n\",\"c\":[\"ABC006\",\"ABC502\",\"ABC503\"]}"
  }
]
```

What I want:

```
[
  {
    "LastWriteTime": "2023-03-07T15:22:07.8269947-05:00",
    "FullName": "\\\\server\\d$\\Program\\logs\\alerts\\2480702_2023-03-07-202100Z_1678220527823.json",
    "Contents": {"a":12345,"b":"This is a test\nof wills.\n","c":["ABC006","ABC502","ABC503"]}
  },
  {
    "LastWriteTime": "2023-03-08T15:18:58.4251682-05:00",
    "FullName": "\\\\server\\d$\\Program\\logs\\alerts\\2480702_2023-03-08-201800Z_1678306738418.json",
    "Contents": {"a":23456,"b":"To\nstack overflow\n","c":["ABC006","ABC502","ABC503"]}
  },
  {
    "LastWriteTime": "2023-03-09T15:06:18.6890386-05:00",
    "FullName": "\\\\server\\d$\\Program\\logs\\alerts\\2480702_2023-03-09-200600Z_1678392378684.json",
    "Contents": {"a":34567,"b":"or not to\nstack overflow\nthat is the question.\n","c":["ABC006","ABC502","ABC503"]}
  }
]
```

This is the part of my script that creates the first output I showed above:

```
$rx = -join ($id, "_.*\.json")
$dir = -join ("\\", $machine, "\d$\\", $appname, "\logs\alerts")
$answer = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach ($machine in $machines)
{
    $arr = Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse |
      Where-Object { $_.Name -match $rx } |
      Select-Object @{ n = 'LastWriteTime'; e = { $_.LastWriteTime } },
        @{ n = 'FullName'; e = { $_.FullName } },
        @{ n = 'Contents'; e = { Get-Content -Path $_.FullName } }
}

$null = $answer.Add($arr)
$answer | Sort-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -as [datetime] }
```

Comment: Seems like you're looking your last expression to be `Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon That worked, THANK YOU! I just had to add a -Depth parameter to ConvertFrom-Json to overcome the default of 2.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Correction: I didn't need the -Depth parameter to the ConvertFrom-Json, I needed it for the ConvertTo-Json at the end.